# Trying to find empty files in other user home directory

Tags: linux, grep, find, cut

I want to search for empty files inside the home directory of the user "adam" for example.

Now i don't know the right path for that user, so I need to get it from  `/etc/passwd` with the following command:

```
grep ^adam: /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6
```

Output: /home/adam (for example)
Then executing this command to find the empty files.

```
find /home/adam -type f -size 0 -print
```

Is it possible to do this with one command?

So I tried this:

```
grep ^adam: /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6 | find -type f -size 0 -print
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Very close ... this is what I'd  do (using one command instead of two):

```
find $(awk -F: '$1=="adam"{print $6}' /etc/passwd) -type f -size 0
```

*(Thanks for the improvement suggestion, Ed)*

With your `grep` & `cut` this would work, too:

```
find $(grep ^adam: /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6) -type f -size 0
```

These two are using **command substitution** ...

If you prefer a `pipe` you could use `xargs`:

```
grep ^adam: /etc/passwd | cut -d: -f6 | xargs -i find "{}" -type f -size 0
```